# Writing nice sentences even if one value is missing

Tags: php

I'm really tired of making "if elseif else" statements do you know a fun way to deal with this :

For the purpose of this example I'll focused on 3 variables but in reallity there are more than 500.

Required variables :

name

Those variables can be empty :

birthdate, city

I want to write a sentence like that :

The user John Doe who is 35 aged and leave in Pittsburg.

But if the birthdate is empty I want to write :

The user John Doe leave in Pittsburg.

And so on....

You can see the expected output and the real array of values here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/CMC8a/1/

I tried multiple ways to approach this issue see more here :

```
<style>
    *{
        font-family: Helvetica;
    }
    label{
        font-size: large;
    }

</style>
<table id="entete">

</table>
<h2><?php echo $data['patient']['nom']['value'] ?> <?php echo $data['patient']['prenom']['value'] ?> <?php echo age_count($data['patient']['ddn']['value']) ?> ans</h2>


<?php
$blocInfoGenerales = new BlocColumnPdf(
        'Informations générales', array(
    $data['patient']['ddn'],
    $data['patient']['sexe'],
    $data['patient']['profession'],
    $data['patient']['villeNaissance']
    , $data['patient']['departement'])
        , 2
);
$blocInfoGenerales->render();
?>
<h3>Antécédents personnels</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Respiratoires : </label><?php echo makeCommaForThoseMCB(array($data['N1']['asthme'], $data['N1']['rhinite'], $data['N1']['bcpo'], $data['N1']['insuffisanceResp'], $data['N1']['chirurgieOrl'], $data['N1']['autreChirurgie'], $data['N1']['allergies'], $data['N1']['old'])) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Cardio-vasculaires et cérébraux : </label><?php echo makeCommaForThoseMCB(array($data['N1']['hypertensionArterielle'], $data['N1']['infarctusMyocarde'], $data['N1']['bcpo'], $data['N1']['insuffisanceCoronaire'], $data['N1']['troubleRythme'], $data['N1']['accidentVasculaireCerebral'], $data['N1']['insuffisanceCardiaque'], $data['N1']['arteriopathie'])) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Autres : </label><?php echo makeCommaForThoseMCB(array($data['N1']['tabagismeActuel'], $data['N1']['tabagismeAncien'], $data['N1']['alcool'], $data['N1']['refluxGastro'], $data['N1']['glaucome'], $data['N1']['diabete'], $data['N1']['hypercholesterolemie'], $data['N1']['hypertriglyceridemie'], $data['N1']['dysthyroidie'], $data['N1']['depression'])) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Antécédents familiaux : </label><?php echo makeCommaForThoseMCB(array($data['N1']['sedentarite'], $data['N1']['syndromeDApneesSommeil'], $data['N1']['obesite'], $data['N1']['dysmorphieFaciale'])) ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<h3>Traitements en cours</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo makeCommaforThisVMB($data['N1']['vidalMultiBox'], 'vidalMultiBox') ?></td>
    </tr>

</table>
<h3>Première visite</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo makeCommaForThoseFields(array($data['suivi1'][0]['dateVisite'], $data['suivi1'][0]['adressePar'], $data['suivi1'][0]['selecMedecinSpecialiste'])) ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo makeCommaForThoseFields(array($data['suivi1'][0]['motifConsultation'])) ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo makeCommaForThoseFields(array($data['suivi1'][0]['taille'], $data['suivi1'][0]['poids'], $data['suivi1'][0]['perimetreCervical'], $data['suivi1'][0]['perimetreAbdominal'])) ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo makeCommaForThoseFields(array($data['suivi1'][0]['PASystolique'], $data['suivi1'][0]['PADiastolique'])) ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label> <?php echo makeCommaForThoseMCB(array($data['suivi1'][0]['profilMaxilofacial'])) ?></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo makeCommaForThoseFields(array($data['suivi1'][0]['autoPASystolique'], $data['suivi1'][0]['autoPADiastolique'])) ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Bilan Biologique :</label>
            <?php
            echo makeCommaForThoseFields(array(
                $data['suivi1'][0]['dateBilan'], $data['suivi1'][0]['glycemie'],
                $data['suivi1'][0]['cholesterolemieTotale'], $data['suivi1'][0]['HDL'],
                $data['suivi1'][0]['LDL'], $data['suivi1'][0]['triglycerides']
            ))
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Clinique :</label> <?php
            echo makeCommaForThoseMCB(
                    array(
                        $data['suivi1'][0]['ronflements'],
                        $data['suivi1'][0]['somnolenceDiurne'],
                        $data['suivi1'][0]['somnolenceConduite'],
                        $data['suivi1'][0]['fatigueMatinale'],
                        $data['suivi1'][0]['cephaleesMatinales'],
                        $data['suivi1'][0]['troubleLibido'],
                        $data['suivi1'][0]['troubleMemoire'],
                        $data['suivi1'][0]['troubleErection'],
                        $data['suivi1'][0]['transpirationNocturne']
            ))
            ?>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td><label>Auto-questionnaires :</label> <?php
            echo makeCommaForThoseFields(
                    array(
                        $data['suivi1'][0]['echelleEpworth'],
                        $data['suivi1'][0]['echellePichot'],
                        $data['suivi1'][0]['echelleDepression'],
                        $data['suivi1'][0]['SJSRCriteresDiagnostiques']
            ))
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php $data['suivi1'][0]['estimationDureeMoyenneDeSommeil']['label'] = 'Estimation durée moyenne de sommeil' ?>
         <td><?php echo makeCommaForThoseFields(array($data['suivi1'][0]['estimationDureeMoyenneDeSommeil']     )) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>
            <label>Exploration fonctionnelle respiratoire :</label>
            <?php
            echo makeCommaForThoseFields(array(
                $data['suivi1'][0]['dateBilan'], $data['suivi1'][0]['glycemie'],
                $data['suivi1'][0]['cholesterolemieTotale'], $data['suivi1'][0]['HDL'],
                $data['suivi1'][0]['LDL'], $data['suivi1'][0]['triglycerides']
            ))
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>


<?php

function count_capitals($s) {
    return strlen(preg_replace('![^A-Z]+!', '', $s));
}

function custom_strtolower($string) {
    if (count_capitals($string) <= 1) {
        return strtolower($string);
    }
    return $string;
}

function makeCommaForThoseFields($elements) {
    $i = 0;
    $response = false;
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['value']) {
            if ($i == 0) {
                $response = '<label>' . $element['label'] . '</label> : ';
                $response .= (isset($element['libelle'])) ? custom_strtolower($element['libelle']) : $element['value'];
                $response .= (isset($element['unit'])&& $element['unit'] != 'NULL') ? ' ' . ($element['unit']) : '';
            } else {
                if ($element['label'] != 'Préciser' && $element['label'] != 'Préciser') {
                    $response .= ', <label>' . custom_strtolower($element['label']) . '</label> : ';
                    $response .= (isset($element['libelle'])) ? custom_strtolower($element['libelle']) : $element['value'];
                    $response .= (isset($element['unit'])&& $element['unit'] != 'NULL') ? ' ' . ($element['unit']) : '';
                } else {
                    $response .= ' (';
                    $response .= (isset($element['libelle'])) ? custom_strtolower($element['libelle']) : $element['value'];
                    $response .= (isset($element['unit']) && $element['unit'] != 'NULL') ? ' ' . ($element['unit']) : '';
                    $response .= ')';
                }
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
    if ($response) {
        $response.='.';
    }
    return $response;
}

function makeCommaforThisVMB($vidalMultiBox, $key) {
    $i = 0;
    $response = false;
    foreach ($vidalMultiBox as $element) {
        $response = $element[$key . '_libelle'] . ' ' . $element[$key . '_val_posologie'] . ' ' . $element[$key . '_id_posologie'] . ', ';
    }

    if ($response) {
        $response = substr($response, 0, -2);
        $response.='.';
    }
    return $response;
}

function makeCommaForThoseMCB($elements) {
    $i = 0;
    $response = false;
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['value'] == 1) {

            if ($i == 0) {
                $response = $element['label'];
            } else {
                $response.= ', ' . strtolower($element['label']);
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
    if ($response) {
        $response.='.';
    }
    return $response;
}

class BlocColumnPdf {

    private $m_title;
    private $elements;
    private $m_colone;
    private $m_id;

    function __construct($title, $p_elements, $p_colone, $id) {
        $this->m_title = $title;
        foreach ($p_elements as $e) {
            $tmp_e = new ElementColumnPdf($e);
            if (!$tmp_e->isEmpty()) {
                $this->elements[] = $tmp_e;
            }
        }

        $this->m_colone = $p_colone;
        return $this;
    }

    function render() {
        $is_empty = true;
        foreach ($this->elements as $e) {
            if (!$e->isEmpty()) {
                $is_empty = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!$is_empty) {
            echo '<h3>' . $this->m_title . '</h3>';
            echo '<table id="' . $this->m_id . '">';
            $lines_elements = array_chunk($this->elements, $this->m_colone);
            foreach ($lines_elements as $line_elements) {
                $this->renderLine($line_elements);
            }

            echo '</table>';
        }
    }

    function renderLine($elements) {
        foreach ($elements as $e) {
            if (!$e->isEmpty()) {
                $is_empty = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!$is_empty) {
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($elements as $e) {
                $e->render();
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }

}

class ElementColumnPdf {

    private $element;

    function __construct($p_element) {
        $this->element = $p_element;
        return $this;
    }

    function render() {
        $text = (isset($this->element['libelle']) && $this->element['libelle']) ? $this->element['libelle'] : $this->element['value'];
        $unit = (isset($this->element['unit']) && $this->element['unit']) ? $this->element['unit'] : '';
        if (!$this->isEmpty()) {
            echo '<td><label>' . $this->element['label'] . '</label> <span class="value">' . $text . '</span><span class="unit">' . $unit . '</span></td>';
        } else {
            echo '<td></td>';
        }
    }

    function isEmpty() {
        if ($this->element['value']) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

The use and abuse of  is because of the tool I'm using to convert HTML to PDF. this tool is doing better with table rather than div

What would you do ?

Comment: No reason for down votes here... probably why nobody added a comment with theirs.

Comment: I think for some users it's a game

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a potentially interesting question.

What you need to do, ideally, is create an array of "things" to say about the person, then make a human-readable list of facts.

Something like this could work well:

```
$things = array();
if( !empty($birthdate)) $things[] = "who is aged ".$birthdate;
if( !empty($city)) $things[] = "lives in ".$city;
```

Then output it:

```
echo "The user ".$name;
if( $things) { // check that there are actually things to say
    $lastthing = array_pop($things);
    if( $things) { // see if there are still things, ie. there were at least two
        echo implode(", ",$things);
        echo " and ";
    }
    echo $lastthing;
}
```

The above structure results in grammatically correct lists, based on the number of items:

1. A
2. A and B
3. A, B and C
4. A, B, C and D
   [and so on]

Comment: @Su4p Well exactly. I don't know why people seem to think this question is "primarily opinion-based" just because you asked "What would you do?" when asking for how to go about solving this problem... Sorry for the "placeholder" answer, but I'm fed up of questions getting closed when I'm halfway through typing. Anyway, answer posted now.

Comment: the array of things is not a bad idea. I have to think about more cases cause the language where the sentence are written is a lot less declarative than english.

Comment: @Su4p What language is it?

Comment: Je suis presque certain qu'en Français, on utilise `A, B et C`, non ? Si c'est le cas, il suffit de remplacer «and» avec «et».

Comment: j'ai rajouté des informations à ma question originale.